# How to recognize if there are any categorical variables that should be encoded as factors in a data.frame?

Tags: r, statistics, categorical-data

I have the following data.frame. How can I recognize if there is any categorical variable that should be encoded as factors in a data.frame?

```
  YEAR  PBE  CBE  PPO  CPO  PFO DINC  CFO RDINC RFP
1  1925 59.7 58.6 60.5 65.8 65.8 51.4 90.9  68.5 877
2  1926 59.7 59.4 63.3 63.3 68.0 52.6 92.1  69.6 899
3  1927 63.0 53.7 59.9 66.8 65.5 52.1 90.9  70.2 883
4  1928 71.0 48.1 56.3 69.9 64.8 52.7 90.9  71.9 884
5  1929 71.0 49.0 55.0 68.7 65.6 55.1 91.1  75.2 895
6  1930 74.2 48.2 59.6 66.1 62.4 48.8 90.7  68.3 874
7  1931 72.1 47.9 57.0 67.4 51.4 41.5 90.0  64.0 791
8  1932 79.0 46.0 49.5 69.7 42.8 31.4 87.8  53.9 733
9  1933 73.1 50.8 47.3 68.7 41.6 29.4 88.0  53.2 752
10 1934 70.2 55.2 56.6 62.2 46.4 33.2 89.1  58.0 811
11 1935 82.2 52.2 73.9 47.7 49.7 37.0 87.3  63.2 847
12 1936 68.4 57.3 64.4 54.4 50.1 41.8 90.5  70.5 845
13 1937 73.0 54.4 62.2 55.0 52.1 44.5 90.4  72.5 849
14 1938 70.2 53.6 59.9 57.4 48.4 40.8 90.6  67.8 803
15 1939 67.8 53.9 51.0 63.9 47.1 43.5 93.8  73.2 793
16 1940 63.4 54.2 41.5 72.4 47.8 46.5 95.5  77.6 798
17 1941 56.0 60.0 43.9 67.4 52.2 56.3 97.5  89.5 830
```

Is this a correct answer?

yes! factor(beef$PBE) has 14 levels, factor(beef$PPO) has 16 levels, factor(beef$CFO) has 15 levels, and the rest cannot be encoded as factor because they have complete 17 levels.

Comment: Should I use this ? `> is.factor(beef)
[1] FALSE`

Comment: The problem is that none of these are factors _yet_. You want to identify categorical variables, but there's not an easily defined answer, because it really depends on the data. You could do something like setting any variable w/fewer than 10 distinct values to a factor, but maybe it's continuous and just has few distinct values.

Comment: @maxliving can you take a look at the update I added at the end of the question? Thanks, Mona.

Comment: This is your call! You decide the data type. For what it seems, you have a time series (YEAR) data type and the rest seem to be numeric or integer. You can coerce any of these data types to the one you want. run `str(data)` to have a look at the actual data types. Then choose if those are rigth or wrong. Finally coerce the data type with functions such as: `as.character()`, `as.factor()`, `as.numeric()`, etc.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about recognizing data and may be better suited for Cross Validated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spacedman makes some very good points that it is in general not desirable to create factors from numeric data willy-nilly. For visualization or some modeling approaches it can be useful, though. I use the utility function below to replace columns with few distinct entries in a `data.frame` by (ordered) factors, I post it below with an example:

```
make_factors <- function(data, max_levels=15) {
    # convert all columns in <data> that are not already factors
    # and that have fewer than <max_levels> distinct values into factors. 
    # If the column is numeric, it becomes an ordered factor.

    stopifnot(is.data.frame(data))
    for(n in names(data)){
        if(!is.factor(data[[n]]) && 
                length(unique(data[[n]])) <= max_levels) {
            data[[n]] <- if(!is.numeric(data[[n]])){
                 as.factor(data[[n]])
            } else {
                 ordered(data[[n]])
            }    
        }
    }
    data
}


# create dataset with one numeric column <foo> with few  distinct entries 
# and one character column <baz> with few  distinct entries :
data <- iris
data <- within(data, {
     foo <- round(iris[, 1])
     baz <- as.character(foo)
})   


table(data$foo)

## 4  5  6  7  8 
## 5 47 68 24  6 

str(data)

## 'data.frame':    150 obs. of  7 variables:
##  $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
##  $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
##  $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
##  $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
##  $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##  $ baz         : chr  "5" "5" "5" "5" ...
##  $ foo         : num  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 5 ...

str(make_factors(data))

## 'data.frame':    150 obs. of  7 variables:
##  $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
##  $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
##  $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
##  $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
##  $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##  $ baz         : Factor w/ 5 levels "4","5","6","7",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 ...
##  $ foo         : Ord.factor w/ 5 levels "4"<"5"<"6"<"7"<..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Your exact question is: "How can I recognize if there is any categorical variable that should be encoded as factors in a data.frame?". Use of "should" here is the crucial part. Why do we encode things as factors anyway?

Factors are used when data are restricted to a number of discrete levels, such as "red", "orange",  or "green" for the colour of a traffic light (yes, some countries have "red+orange", or "flashing orange" as well, add these to the levels of your factor). An ordered factor is used when data is categorical but has a defined order, such as "small", "medium", "large, or "extra large".

If your data is numbers, it is most likely that it should remain as numbers, unless it is already a numerical coding for an underlying category (eg 1=male, 2=female). There's very few reasons to convert anything else numeric into factors unless you have only a few values and statistical analysis using categorical methods makes more sense than continuous numerical methods.